# How to apply validation for image resolution on click of button that "choose file of recommended resolution"

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have <input type= file and a button to update that file 0n server. I want a function in which on click of a button it will validate an uploaded file resolution (width and height)

Answer (score 0):

```js
function validateImageFile(fileInput) {
  const file = fileInput.files[0];
  const reader = new FileReader();

  reader.onload = function(event) {
    const img = new Image();
    img.onload = function() {
      const width = this.width;
      const height = this.height;

      if (width === 0 || height === 0) {
        alert("Invalid image file. Please select a valid image.");
        fileInput.value = "";
        // added a condtion , you chnage it according to your need
      } else if (width < 600 || height < 400) {
        alert("Image resolution is low. Please select an image with at least 600 x 400 resolution.");
        fileInput.value = "";
      } else {
        // Image is valid.
      }
    };
    img.src = event.target.result;
  };
  reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}
```

Comment: what is fileInput in validateImageFile(fileInput) is it a id of input type file

Comment: send me your html `input ` code

Comment: `<input type="file" id="imageInput" onchange="validateImageFile(this)">
`